Table django_celery_beat_clockedschedule' doesn't exist
django_celery_beat_clockedschedule' doesn't exist
I successfully installed django-celery-beat package with django==2.1. All migrations are also applied successfully, There are five models are showing in django such as clocked, crontabs, intervals etc. Although when i open there detailed view it says Table '....django_celery_beat_clockedschedule' doesn't exist.
It shows the same error for all of them.
Note: I also tried too many time to unapply all migrations and reinstalling the django-celery-beat package with no luck
